# Compilation Error - org.testng does not exist

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, github

I'm trying to execute Maven project from Jenkins stored in GitHub and receiving below errors

When I execute the same in my local (Eclipse) no issues.

Set the correct JDK path in Global configuration.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\ExtentReportListener\ExtentReporterNG.java:[9,17] error: package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\ExtentReportListener\ExtentReporterNG.java:[10,17] error: package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\ExtentReportListener\ExtentReporterNG.java:[11,17] error: package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\ExtentReportListener\ExtentReporterNG.java:[12,17] error: package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\ExtentReportListener\ExtentReporterNG.java:[13,17] error: package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\ExtentReportListener\ExtentReporterNG.java:[14,17] error: package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\ExtentReportListener\ExtentReporterNG.java:[15,21] error: package org.testng.xml does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\ExtentReportListener\ExtentReporterNG.java:[21,41] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class IReporter
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\ExtentReportListener\ExtentReporterNG.java:[24,33] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class XmlSuite
[ERROR] location: class ExtentReporterNG
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\ExtentReportListener\ExtentReporterNG.java:[24,59] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ISuite
[ERROR] location: class ExtentReporterNG
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\ExtentReportListener\ExtentReporterNG.java:[45,29] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class IResultMap
[ERROR] location: class ExtentReporterNG
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\retryanalyzer\RetryTransform.java:[6,17] error: package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\retryanalyzer\RetryTransform.java:[7,29] error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\retryanalyzer\RetryTransform.java:[9,39] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class IAnnotationTransformer
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\retryanalyzer\RetryTransform.java:[11,23] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ITestAnnotation
[ERROR] location: class RetryTransform
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\retryanalyzer\RetryAnalyzer.java:[3,17] error: package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\retryanalyzer\RetryAnalyzer.java:[4,17] error: package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\ADMIN\git\MavenDemoProject\SeleniumMaven_Git_Jenkins\src\main\java\com\qa\easy\retryanalyzer\RetryAnalyzer.java:[6,38] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class IRetryAnalyzer
```

Comment: I have a theory but could you post your pom file please, just the dependencies. Also what's the OS where your Jenkins is installed, is it Windows?

Comment: @StephenK Messages that start with "C:\Users..." will certainly not come from Linux.

Comment: Hi Azar, welcome to SO. Please have a read through [ask] and especially how to create [mcve]. Just a stack trace with no code is impossible to help you.

Comment: You need to verify it runs on commandline on your machine. This most likely isn't a jenkins issue, but theres some difference between what you specify in your pom and whats specified in your eclipse project. I.e. make sure you have testng in scope test as dependency in your pom.

Answer (score 3):

Comment out or remove `<scope>test</scope>`  from testng dependency in pom file. 
Save the pom file and then compile, It should work.

Answer (score 0):

clear data from .m2/repository and try.

Answer (score 0):

Two things

1. Check you `POM.xml` and also if Jenkins runs on the server which has proxy then you have to configure it.
2. Clear the cache from `.m2/repository`.

If this doesn't work then share your `POM.xml`

Answer (score 0):

As per your code in pom.xml, remove the scope tag.It will works